# Request Failed Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '500'. The status text of response is 'internal server error'. null

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013, dashboard

I have created the "Business Intelligence Center Site" and I have to create dashboards.I have activated the required features at site level and site collection level also.Yet when I click on the 'dashboard design' in performancepoint tab of PerformancePoint Content list ribbon, it is showing me error as "Request Failed Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is '500'. The status text of response is 'internal server error'. null ". It was working fine at starting. And I already downloaded the "Dashboard Designer" too. But later on that dashboard designer too is not connecting with the server. Why is it happening so. I did lot of finding and tried many solutions yet it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Event log on the server.  You may have run out of RAM on the SharePoint server.